# Prove that there exists a $g \in N(\phi)^\perp$ such that $\phi(g)=1$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am practising with a past exam of my functional analysis course and I am stuck on the following question:

> Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space and let $\phi: H 
> \to \mathbb R$ be a non-zero bounded (hence continuous) linear functional. Prove that there exists a $g \in (N(\phi))^\perp$ such that $\phi(g)=1$. (Where the $N$ denotes the null space).

**Attempt.**  We may write that every $x\in H$ can be represented $x=n +n_c$ where $n$ is in the null space and $n_c$ in its complement. (Since $H= N(\phi) \oplus
 N (\phi)^\perp$ ). Then by linearity we get:
$$\phi(x)= \phi(n+n_c)=\phi(n)+\phi(n_c)= 0+ \phi(n_c)\neq 0 \text{ since } n_c \not \in N(\phi).$$
Since $n$ lies in the null space of $\phi$. Now we simply consider:
$$ g:= \frac{1}{\phi(n_c)} n_c \in N(\phi) ^\perp$$
which would have the desired property. Is my reasoning close?

Comment: Your reasoning is close, but doesn't quite make sense -- you can't define $g$ this way before you've defined $x$ and made sure that $\phi(n_c) \neq 0$!

Comment: Yes I see, my reasoning is a bit jumbled. Your argument makes sense. I try to do it for all $x$ in the space, but I just need to construct a single $g$. Indeed if $n_c=0$ in my argument I run into trouble.

Comment: Exactly right! Very good self-reflection :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $N(\phi)^\perp$ is a subspace, it suffices to find some $x \in N(\phi)^\perp$ such that $\phi(x) \neq 0$: then we can just define $g = x/\phi(x)$.

Well, suppose for contradiction that this didn't happen. Then $\phi(x) = 0$ for all $x \in N(\phi)^\perp$. By definition, we also have $\phi(x) = 0$ for all $x \in N(\phi)$! As you noted, $H = N(\phi) \oplus N(\phi)^\perp$, so we conclude that $\phi = 0$. This contradicts the assumption that $\phi$ is nonzero.